# Using result of SQL Query as table name in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, tablename

I've to write a ***trigger*** on my table which will perform the following functions.

- Before Update on row, check price of Item
- If price has changed from the last price, then select the table name, where to insert the item name, from another table having type of item and the associated table name.
- Insert the item name in the selected table.

To put simply i've a table(*TypeNameTable*) having item categories and corresponding table names, if the price of item has changed then i've to get the table name from the *TypeNameTable* and insert the item name in the table, which is retrieved from *TypeNameTable*.
I'm not able to insert into table when I get the table names dynamically. Please suggest how to do it.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
BEGIN

  #declare countryTableName varchar(50);
  declare itemPrice int;
  declare itemTableName text;

  IF (New.Price != Old.Price) THEN
    SET countryTableName = (select `ItemManager`.`TypeNames`.`TypeTableName` 
                              from `ItemManager`.`TypeNames` 
                             where `ItemManager`.`TypeNames`.`ItemType` = NEW.ItemType);

   INSERT INTO `ItemManager`.itemTableName
     ( `ItemName`, `ItemPrice`,
   VALUES
    ( NEW.Name, New.Price );

  END IF;
END$$
```

I get the error

> `ItemManager`.itemTableName doesn't exists.

Comment: You have enough rep to know how to use [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) rather than HTML

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Sorry for the poor formatting. I'm really stuck with the problem here and can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answering my own question.*

Figured out that using **Dynamic SQL** is not allowed in ***MySQL triggers*** . 
The restrictions are listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html). 

However it's possible in Oracle where we can use **PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION** which executes the query in new context, and hence supports **Dynamic SQL**. 

Example listed [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/ordevworkbook/chapter/ch16s.html) at ***Point 27*** .

Comment: You asked about MySQL, but your answer is about Oracle.

Comment: @Devart I've told that its not possible in MySql but Oracle supports Dynamic SQL.

Comment: So, you had wanted to use MySQL, but then chose Oracle. But, why don't you want to change database design? If it is possible - do not store table names in rows. Use table relations.

Answer (score 0):

You could CONCAT() your INSERT statement into a variable and execute that as PREPARED STATEMENT, someting like

```
...
SET @sql := CONCAT( 'INSERT INTO ', itemTableName, ' ... ' );
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
...
```

afaik this is the only way to process dynamically generated SQL in stored routines and triggers.

Comment: I get the following error when using like this:ERROR 1336: Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: hm, I was not aware this is limited to STORED PROCEDUREs; sorry, I have no idea in that case

Comment: MYSQL triggers cannot execute Dynamic SQL statements. Even if the statement is being fired from a stored procedure that the trigger is calling.

Answer (score -1):

If it is possible, I'd suggest you to change design a little. Instead of different tables you can create one table `itemTable`.

```
...
IF (New.Price != Old.Price) THEN

 INSERT INTO `ItemManager`.`itemTable`
   ( `ItemName`, `ItemPrice`,
 VALUES
  ( NEW.Name, New.Price );

END IF;
...
```

If there are different item properties, this table can be a parent table for specific child tables.